# XSS and file_get_contents?

Tags: php, xss, file-get-contents

My url is like `page.php?path=content/x/y/z/aaa.md`. Is the following php code XSS-secure?

```
include "Parsedown.php";

function path_purifier($path) {
  if(substr($path, 0, 8) !== "content/")
    return null;
  if (strpos($path,'..') !== false)
    return null;
  return "./" . $path;
}

$parsedown = new Parsedown();
$path = $_GET['path'];
$path = path_purifier($path);
echo $parsedown->text(file_get_contents($path));
```

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, looks secure enough, but still not perfect. You also need to call `is_file()` and ensure it returns true, before you call `file_get_contents()`. Also to make it even safer you can implement a **CSRF** protection on top of it.

Also, keep in mind, that some hosting providers don't allow relative paths. So if a path like `'/content/x/y/file.md'` might work on you local machine, keep in mind that on some hosters it will not. So you'd better always use absolute paths like `__DIR__ . '/content/x/y/file.md'`